# Why the query doesn't return the displayname as it does in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have this code, if I execute it in phpmyadmin it works well, but when I try it in php it just doesn't work. It returns "0 results".

sql:

```
SET @felhasz := (SELECT user_id FROM `items_subtitles` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY SUM(status) DESC LIMIT 1);SELECT displayname FROM `users` WHERE id=@felhasz;
```

php:

```
$sql = "SET @felhasz := (SELECT user_id FROM `items_subtitles` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY SUM(status) DESC LIMIT 1);SELECT displayname FROM `users` WHERE id=@felhasz;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "" . $row["displayname"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run multiple queries in one call to [`query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). Instead, split your query into two calls e.g.

```
$sql = "SET @felhasz := (SELECT user_id FROM `items_subtitles` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY SUM(status) DESC LIMIT 1);";
$conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
$sql = "SELECT displayname FROM `users` WHERE id=@felhasz;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Or you could just combine them into one by replacing the variable in the second query with the value from the first:

```
$sql = "SELECT displayname FROM `users` WHERE id=(SELECT user_id FROM `items_subtitles` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY SUM(status) DESC LIMIT 1);";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Note that you could also use [`multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) but that complicates getting the result set from the second query (see the manual for how to deal with that).